# error en corchete

Tags: java

Buenos días familia,
Estoy muy verde en java y llevo horas intentando solucionar un fallo muy tonto y no doy con la tecla. Me da error por un corchete, a ver si veis el fallo y me contais, Gracias de ante mano.

```
public double retirar(){
            if(saldo<= 0){
          System.out.println("no hay saldo suficiente");
          return this.saldo;
           }
            else if (saldo>=cantidad){ 
           System.out.println("retirar dinero" +cantidad);
        return this.cantidad;                   
            }
```

}- en este corchete me da el fallo...

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que te hace falta devolver un valor cuando saldo está entre 0 y cantidad.
Por otro lado, podrías mejorar la legibilidad del código identándolo correctamente. Aunque en Java no es obligatorio (en Python, por ejemplo, si) si es conveniente. Te adjunto mi propuesta. Mira a ver si te funciona, cambiando XXX por el valor a devolver en el caso de que saldo esté entre 0 y cantidad.

```
public double retirar(){
        if(saldo<= 0){
            System.out.println("no hay saldo suficiente");
            return this.saldo;
        }
        else if (saldo>=cantidad){ 
            System.out.println("retirar dinero" +cantidad);
            return this.cantidad;                   
        }
        else{
            return XXX;//lo que tenga que devolver cuando saldo> 0 y saldo < cantidad
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es el corchete en sí.

Tienes básicamente dos problemas:

- La variable `cantidad` debe ser pasada en parámetro al método, para saber cuánto dinero hay que retirar. Se supone que la variable `saldo` está dentro del ámbito del método, así que no nos metemos con eso.
- Hay un error de lógica. El método debe evaluar al menos: que el saldo no sea `0` o negativo; que la cantidad a retirar no es mayor que el saldo; que la cantidad a retirar no es cero o negativa.
- También, se puede almacenar el resultado final en una variable, y hacer un solo `return` al salir de los bloques condicionales.

Observa este código a manera de ejemplo.

Probaremos el método pasándole tres valores distintos.

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/OHYMB43491)**</kbd>

```
class Rextester
{  
    private static double dblSaldo=7000.00;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        /*Probando el método con tres valores distintos*/
        retirar(420.99);
        retirar(100000.30);
        retirar(0);

    }

    public static double retirar(double dblCantidad){
        double dblNuevoSaldo=dblSaldo;

        if(dblSaldo<=0){
            System.out.println("no hay saldo suficiente");
        }else if(dblCantidad<=0){
            System.out.println("Nada que retirar: "+dblCantidad);
        }else if(dblSaldo>=dblCantidad){
            dblNuevoSaldo=dblSaldo-dblCantidad;
            System.out.println("Se ha retirado: " + String.format("%,.2f",dblCantidad)+ " El nuevo saldo es: " +String.format("%,.2f",dblNuevoSaldo));
        }else{
            System.out.println("No puede ser. Quieres retirar: " + String.format("%,.2f", dblCantidad)+ " Pero tu saldo es: " +String.format("%,.2f",dblSaldo));        
        }
        return dblNuevoSaldo;                   
    }
}
```

---

### Resultado de la prueba:

```
Se ha retirado: 420.99 El nuevo saldo es: 6,579.01
No puede ser. Quieres retirar: 100,000.30 Pero tu saldo es: 7,000.00
Nada que retirar. Pediste que se retire: 0.0
```